# Why the directive encapsulate my scope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I have a selector looks like this:

```
 <ui-select theme="bootstrap"
             name="targets_selected"
             ng-model="campaign_offer.target_audience_id"
             aa-field-name="{{'_TargetAudience_' | i18n}}"
             required aa-val-msg>
    <ui-select-match placeholder="{{'_SelectTargetAudience_' | i18n}}">{{$select.selected.name}}
    </ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices
      repeat="ta.id as ta in possible_targets">
      {{ta.name}}
    </ui-select-choices>

  </ui-select>
```

I all  works fine,
But when I'm tried to make it a reusable ui component I ran into some issue.

I wrote the following code

```
angular.module("commonModule").directive "targetAudienceSelect", ->
  scope: {targets: '=ctvTargets', selected_target: '=ctvSelectedTarget'}
  restrict: "A"
  replace: true
  templateUrl: "/assets/directives/selectors/target_audience_selector.html"



<div class="form-group" ng-form="formTAC">
  <label for="TargetAudience" class="col-md-12 nopadding">{{'_TargetAudience_' | i18n}}</label>

  <div id="TargetAudience" class="">
    <ui-select theme="bootstrap"
               name="targets_selected"
               ng-model="selected_target"
               ng-change="target_changed(selected_target)"
               aa-field-name="{{'_TargetAudience_' | i18n}}"
               required aa-val-msg>
      <ui-select-match placeholder="{{'_SelectTargetAudience_' | i18n}}">{{$select.selected.name}}
      </ui-select-match>
      <ui-select-choices
        repeat="ta.id as ta in targets">
        {{ta.name}}
      </ui-select-choices>

    </ui-select>
  </div>
</div>
```

And for using it I put the follwoing

```
<div target-audience-select ctv-targets=possible_targets ctv-selected-target=campaign_offer.target_audience_id></div>
```

I can see the items in the selector. but when selecting an item the selected item in my controller does not change, it does when I'm just copy paste the directives html to my view, but not when using it as directive.

I'm using the [ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select) as select directive

added a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/YJP7PqrNahceWe7guFsm)

how to fix it?

Comment: Your snippet does not run. Please fix it first

Comment: sorry it shouldn't be runnalbe

Comment: Well, you are using isolated scope and properties mapping looks fine. So it should be worked after selecting inside directive. Is this your complete directive code? Are you modifying anything out of the angular context?

Comment: Te directive is updated.. but the controller scope (the binding to campaign_offer.target_audience_id) not seems to work